# Let $p$ be a prime, and $k \in \mathbb N$. What is the order of $U(p^{k})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Q: Let $p$ be a prime, and $k \in \mathbb N$. What is the order of $U(p^{k}) = |U(p^{k})|$?

I understand that $|U(p)| = (p-1)$.

With some experimenting I suspect that $|U(p^{k})| = (p-1)*p^{k-1} $.

How can I (dis)prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|U(n)|=\phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is called as the Euler phi function.

$\phi(n)=|\{a\in \mathbb N|  1\leq a<n  \ and\  (a,n)=1 \}|$  and it is easy to see that $\phi(p)=p-1$

Now, let's try to find $\phi(p^k)$. Notice that if $(a,p^k)>1$ then $p$ must divides $a$. Thus, $a$ must be of the form $a=kp$ where $k\in \{ 1,2,...,p^{k-1}-1\}$ so,there are $p^{k-1}-1$ elements which is not desired and in total we have $p^k-1$ elements.

Hence, $\phi(p^k)=(p^k-1)-(p^{k-1}-1)=p^k-p^{k-1}=(p-1)p^{k-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Edited: The only integers sharing a nontrivial common factor with $p^{k}$ are $p, 2p, 3p, \ldots$. How many of them are there in $U(p^k)$?

Comment: What about $2p$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Good point.